# Is it possible to store username in FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser with Firebase for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to store user information. Right now I created a collection `Users` with an email, an username and a profile image. I can get all this data using a method `Future<CloudUser> getUserDetails({required String userId});`. Is it possible to store the username in the class `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`? so I don't have to use the method `getUserDetails` everytime I want to get the username. I am using flutter and firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store the username in the class
> FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?

You can store the username in the `displayName` property of the [`User`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) class.

You can set this value by modifying the user object with the `updateDisplayName()` method, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) in the doc.